# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed error in IIS7 & CruiseControl.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, cruisecontrol.net

I've set-up a cruisecontrol.net server with IIS7. I want to be able to view the web dashboard. Everything has worked for me before fine in IIS6, but now it seems to be broke in IIS7.

If I browser to: http://192.168.93.133:21234/default.aspx

I get the following error:
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://192.168.93.133:21234/default.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 5:.NET

It looks like ASP.NET isn't being hit when I request the page.  But as far as I know the application pool of the site is set to .NET, and I don't know how to check whether ASP.NET is configured correctly with IIS7.

Does anyone know if this a problem which can be rectified in IIS7?
Has anyone test CruiseControl.NET from installation in IIS7?

Answer (score 1):

I run cc.net with IIS7. Use the server manager and go to *Roles - Web Server (IIS)*. On the page that is displayed you will see the installed *Role Services*. If ASP.Net is not listed you can added it on the same page: There is a command *Add Role Services*.